# Не связывается парсинг и wysibb

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Собственно, сам код выложил [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread1264033.html).

Пробовал менять парсинги. Ничего не выходит. Текст не конвертируется в html. На выходе получается `[b]text[/b]`.

Comment: связ**ывае**тся, проб**о**вал

Comment: Вопрос решён.